# Finding combination of elements of a list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python code to pick out all possible combinations from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list)

I have a list say [1, 2, 3]. I want to find the all the combinations

```
C(3,1)
[1] [2] [3]

C(3,2)
[1,2] [2,3] [1,3]

C(3,3)
[1,2,3]
```

Is there some module/library for doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
>>> import itertools

>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 1))
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]

>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]

>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 3))
[(1, 2, 3)]
```

or generally for your `C`:

```
def C(a, b):
    return list(itertools.combinations(range(1,a+1), b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the itertools library: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Comment: Even if a link is what is asked for, don't just post a link. Show how to do what he's asking, or at least quote from the source. If all you have to contribute is a link, post it as a comment.